# SSIS 2012 Package run through DOS commands

Tags: ssis, package

I need to run the `SSIS 2012 packag`e through batch file,Package is executing fine in command prompt,But not able to pass parameter run time values via commands ,While run in DOS prompt ,
throwing error like

> SET is not recognized as command

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\ Binn \DTExec.exe" /f  "D:\SSIS Deployment\Test Reports\Move Files . dtsx"
/SET \Package. Variables[Report Root Path].Value;"D:\\Development\\PPY"
/SET \Package. Variables[Run Status].Value; "NORM";
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there are space "**Package. Variables**"

Just remove the space and try .

Answer (score 0):

remove the last `;` and try it again.

this works fine for me:

```
c:\tmp>dtexec /f  "test.dtsx" /SET   \Package.Variables[a].Value;"a"    /SET \Package.Variables[b].Value;"b"
```

howerver, this one will give me a similar error:

```
c:\tmp>dtexec /f  "test.dtsx" /SET   \Package.Variables[a].Value;"a"    /SET \Package.Variables[b].Value;"b";
Argument ""\Package.Variables[b].Value;b;"" for option "set" is not valid.
```